# Game messaging on mobile platforms?

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile

Does anyone have recommendations on messaging for multi player games on mobile platforms?
I assume SMS would be too expensive for the average player.

I'm not talking about lots of real-time messages, but simply one message per player per round to all other players.

Is there any available messaging that is cross platform (say, windows mobile to/from iphone, android, etc.)?

add'l info: the constraint I have (may not be solid) is that it should be peer-to-peer -- no server needed.

Answer (score 3):

If your mobile devices got an internet connection: Use a webapplication with a (restful) webservice. Should work on every platform you mentioned.

The mobile application connects to the server after every round and collects the messages.

I don't think there exists a platform agnostic peer-to-peer solution for mobile plattforms, besides that: It wouldn't scale well in the situation you describe. Imagine:

Having 10 Users means that after every round every user sends 9 messages. Now imagine having 10'000 users on your network... Short: Peer-to-peer isn't the solution you're looking for.